# No entiendo porque no me esta funcionando el ciclo For

Tags: python, lista, funciones, bucle-for, condiciones

Buenas tardes comunidad!

Tengo un problemita con con un código que estoy haciendo para a partir de una lista de números, devolver solamente los números primos de dicha lista en una lista nueva

El siguiente código esta diseñado para detectar cuando un numero es primo y cuando no. El problema es que me detecta solamente el primer numero primo de la lista (en caso de que el primer numero de la lista sea primo, me lo agrega a la lista nueva) pero el ciclo for no avanza de la primera posicion

Si por otro lado, el primer numero no es primo, el ciclo for no me arroja ningun resultado, ni me agregar ningun elemento a la lista

```
soloNumerosPrimos = []
listaNumeros = list(range(2,101))

def ListaNumerosPrimos(lista):
    divisores = 0
    for i in lista:
        for u in range(1,i+1):
            if i % u == 0:
                divisores += 1
        if divisores == 2:
            soloNumerosPrimos.append(i)
    print(soloNumerosPrimos)

ListaNumerosPrimos(listaNumeros)
```

Lo que me genera mas duda aun es que cuando borro todo el código y pruebo si efectivamente el elemento iterador i me abarca todos los elementos de la lista, efectivamente asi es, pero con las demas lineas de codigo es como si el ciclo for se detuviera en la primera vuelta

```
soloNumerosPrimos = []
listaNumeros = list(range(2,101))

def ListaNumerosPrimos(lista):
    divisores = 0
    for i in lista:
        print(i)
        

ListaNumerosPrimos(listaNumeros)
```

En este caso, efectivamente la i me abarca todos los numeros

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Nunca vuelves a cero la variable `divisores`.

Comment: @CandidMoe Muchas gracias Candid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás metiendo `divisores` en el cope equivocado.

Suponiendo que el primer número es 2.

```
divisores = 0
for i in lista:
    # i = 2 en primera iteración
    # i+1 = 3 en primera subiteración
    # --------------
    # i = 3 en segunda iteración
    # i+1 = 4 en segunda iteración
    for u in range(1,i+1):
        # u = 1 en primera subiteración primera iteración
        # u = 2 en segunda subiteración primera iteración
        # -----------------------
        # u = 1 en primera subiteración segunda iteración
        # u = 2 en segunda subiteración segunda iteración
        # u = 3 en tercera subiteración segunda iteración
        if i % u == 0: 
            # 2 % 1 = 0 en primera subiteración primera iteración
            # 2 % 2 = 0 en segunda subiteración primera iteración
            # ------------------------------------------
            # 3 % 1 = 0 en primera subiteración segunda iteración
            # 3 % 2 = 1 en segunda subiteración segunda iteración
            # 3 % 3 = 0 en segunda subiteración segunda iteración
            divisores += 1
        # divisores = 1 en primera subiteración primera iteración
        # divisores = 2 en segunda subiteración primera iteración
        # ------------------------------------------
        #(divisores nunca es resetado, por lo que sigue valiendo 2
        # divisores = 3 en primera subiteración segunda iteración
        # divisores = 3 en segunda subiteración segunda iteración
        # divisores = 4 en tercera subiteración segunda iteración
        if divisores == 2:
            soloNumerosPrimos.append(i)
print(soloNumerosPrimos)
```

Con esto te puedes dar cuenta que esta en el lugar incorrecto, basta con meter `divisores` al scope del primer `for`

```
soloNumerosPrimos = []
listaNumeros = list(range(2,101))

def ListaNumerosPrimos(lista):
    for i in lista:
        divisores = 0
        for u in range(1,i+1):
            if i % u == 0:
                divisores += 1
        if divisores == 2:
            soloNumerosPrimos.append(i)
    print(soloNumerosPrimos)

ListaNumerosPrimos(listaNumeros)
```

Comment: Claro entiendo! Digamos que si coloco la variable divisores dentro del scope global de la función, a partir de la segunda iteracion (siempre que el numero sea primo), la variable va a aumentar su valor en 2 cada vez , por lo tanto nunca volvería a ser 2 correcto?